# Two UIviewControllers inside UIScrollview - how to call methods between them

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I have problem with calling methods from one `UIViewController` by another `UIViewController`.
Currently I have `UIScroll` view with two `UIViewControllers`.
I want to change something in second one and see results in first one.

I try to do this in this way:

Inside function of second `UIViewController`:

```
-(void)doSomething:(){

    FirsOneViewController *firstVC = [FirsOneViewController alloc] init];
    [firstVC changeUnits:0];
}
```

Function is called but I don't se any changes in first controller.

BR,
Paul

Comment: That because you recreated your first vc instead of holding his weak property...

Comment: Are you using storyboards??

Comment: yes.[self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCone"]];
    [self addChildViewController:[self.storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"VCtwo"]];

Answer (score 0):

From your code I see you create a new instance of FirstViewController and so there is no reason why the current instance inside the scrollview would receive this message.

You need to send the changeUnits: message to the current FirstViewController, so you need a reference to it. To do this you may want to think about creating a protocol, so that you parent container (the scrollview) is notified by the SecondViewController and then notifies the FirstViewController. A simpler(and lazier) solution is make the SecondViewController have a strong reference to the FirstViewController (though this solution may bite you in the future).

Comment: Can you provide me any tutorial how to do this? You mean delegate?

Comment: Yes, I meant using the delegate pattern, depending on how new you are to iOS (and Objective C for that matter) this may or may not be useful to you http://www.raywenderlich.com/46988/ios-design-patterns

Answer (score 0):

As said in other answers you are creating a new instance of FirsOneViewController instead of referencing to the one you already have.

Here are three ways of doing what you are asking:

**Delegation**:
The FirstViewController should be the delegate of the SecondViewController (as the secondViewController is calling methods on the FirstViewController). You should tell the SecondViewController that the FirstViewController is its delegate in what ever class initialises the two viewControllers.

From what you have said so far this seems like your best option.

**NSNotification**:
This could be good option if you think more than one object will want to listen to the change in the SecondViewController. Just post an NSNotification in the SecondViewController and add an NSNotification listener in the FirstViewController

**Singleton**:
if there should only ever be one instance of the FirstViewController in existence then make it a singleton. By making a class initialiser method. so that you can create/get the current instance of the object from anywhere in your appellation.

Hope this helped.